# hardware makes excel macros quicker?

Tags: excel, hardware, vba

I have a question about computer hardware which I think I know the answer to, but I want to be sure. I have a macro script that I believe to be coded well, but how can I increase the speed at which excel processes the macro? I have a 4 GB ram. Would more ram (i.e. 32 GB) help it to run faster?

My smallest file takes 2 hours to complete the macro run.

Finally, how much time does the following command actually save (in terms of percentage)?

```
Application.screenupdating=False
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: What does your macro actually do? There is no one single magic optimisation which will make all macros faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many complicated formulas in your file - **changing calculation options may help**.

Change calculation to Manual (careful with that, you have to recalculate specyfic cells by macro if you need some cells to be up to date while macro is running)

[image: excel enabling manual calculation]

---

**Enable multi-threading** (Excel 2013 and future versions only)

[image: excel 2013 multi threading]

---

I took images from [here (howtogeek.com)](http://www.howtogeek.com/162219/how-to-change-the-automatic-calculation-and-multi-threading-features-in-excel-2013/).

I think more ram will not help, but you can see how much memory Excel is using. If you have 4GB and you have a lot of free ram when your macro is going - adding more memory will not help. **Im not sure**, but I think Excel is not able to use more than 2GB.

---

If you are using Excel 2013 you can buy faster CPU with more cores.

---

If your macro uses big text files, and you are seeking a lot - SSD hard drive also may help.

---

> how much time does the following command actually save (in terms of
>   percentage

I think not much. Why you can't just try it and see?

---

Consider using more powerful data processing tool, like MS Access or more powerful database engine (like SQL Server), at least for pre-processing your data.